# What is the one thing I am going to forget on the math subject GRE tomorrow?

Tags: big-list, gre-exam

As I finish up my final study session for the subject test tomorrow, I was wondering if anyone had some general advice/ often forgotten facts that might come in handy.

Answer (score 5):

I hated myself for forgetting Sylow theorems (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylow_theorems#Sylow_theorems). They would solve instantly one of the hard problems..

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to register for the exam.

You will forget to bring adequate photo identification.

You will get the date and/or time wrong and miss the exam.

You will enter your name or SSN wrong on the form and will get no credit.

You will forget to sleep the night before, and to eat the morning of the exam.

You will certainly forget to bring water.